# How old is the idea of effector islands in fungi?

Tags: biology

When was the word mesosynteny first used to describe the unique features of fungal genomes? How old is the discovery?

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1364-3703.2009.00591.x/pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of *mesosynteny* was proposed in 2011 in this paper:

> [Hane JK, Rouxel T, Howlett BJ, Kema GH, Goodwin SB, Oliver RP. A novel mode of chromosomal evolution peculiar to filamentous Ascomycete fungi. Genome Biol. 2011 May 24;12(5):R45.](http://www.genomebiology.com/2011/12/5/R45#B14)

which says:

> This pattern is characterized by the conservation of gene content in chromosomes, without conservation of gene order or orientation; that is, synteny without co-linearity. We propose to call this sequence conservation 'mesosynteny' to distinguish it from micro- and macrosynteny. Mesosynteny appears to be peculiar to the filamentous Ascomycetes (syn. Pezizomycotina), particularly in the class Dothideomycetes.